# Getting Invalid address or Invalid Params when deploying new contract on test network with Parity

Tags: contract-development, web3js, parity

I am trying to deploy new contract on the net and I get two errors depending how exactly how I do it. Since I can not get ABI compiling contract on Parity I use `solc --abi` to get it. Now depending if I use compiled code or compile it on Parity I get one of two following errors:

> ..node_modules/web3/lib/web3/formatters.js:271
>   
>     throw new Error('invalid address');
>
> Error: invalid address - (when compiling contract with web3 on Parity)

or

> Error: Invalid params - (when using contract compiled with solc)

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
var Web3 = require("web3");
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

web3.eth.defaultAccount=web3.eth.accounts[0]

var source = "" +
"contract test {\n" +
"   function multiply(uint a) returns(uint d) {\n" +
"       return a * 7;\n" +
"   }\n" +
"}\n";
//var compiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(source);

var compiled = 0x606060405260788060106000396000f360606040526000357c010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000090048063c6888fa1146039576035565b6002565b34600257605160048080359060200190919050506067565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b60006007820290506073565b91905056;

console.log(compiled);

var abi = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"a","type":"uint256"}],"name":"multiply","outputs":[{"name":"d","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"}]

web3.eth.contract(abi).new({data: compiled}, function (err, contract) {
    if(err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
        // callback fires twice, we only want the second call when the contract is deployed
    } else if(contract.address){
        var myContract = contract;
        console.log('address: ' + myContract.address);
    }
});
```

It is worth noting that calling:

```
web3.eth.compile.solidity(source);
```

gives:

> 0x606060405260308060106000396000f3606060405260e060020a6000350463c6888fa18114601c575b6002565b346002576007600435026060908152602090f3

while `solc --bin` gives:

> 0x606060405260788060106000396000f360606040526000357c010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000090048063c6888fa1146039576035565b6002565b34600257605160048080359060200190919050506067565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b60006007820290506073565b91905056

Shouldn't they give same outcome?

Comment: You don't need the newlines in the source. Its actually better to leave them out

Comment: Also, the issue is that you need quotes around the bytecode. i.e. var compiled = "0x6060....."

Comment: @TjadenHess tried both and now I get Error: invalid address in both cases. Thrown at formatters.js

Comment: Oh, that's because you need a `from: ` field in the tx object in the `new` call. Just put `from:eth.coinbase` before the data field.

Comment: @TjadenHess added from:web3.eth.accounts[0]  and still same same issue .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in Parity 1.3.0. After updating to 1.3.2 it is working fine.

More details [here](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/issues/2416)

Comment: issue still on 2.1.1